# Odoo 11. I can not create a new field in the product.template model

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-11

I am new programming in Odoo, I need to add a calculated field to the product.template model, this field will then be used to filter with "domain" in a view.

The problem is that I do not know why, the field is not being created.

I've searched everywhere, and I seem to be doing the right order, but there's definitely something I'm doing wrong.

**__init__.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from . import models
```

**models\ __init__.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from . import punto_pedido
```

**models\punto_pedido.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import api, fields, models, _

class Punto_Pedido(models.Model):
_inherit = "product.template"
x_punto_pedido = fields.Boolean(compute='_CalcularPunto', string='Esta en punto de pedido')

@api.one
def _CalcularPunto(self):
self.x_punto_pedido = True
```

I hope you can help me

Thank you very much

The original code: 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/OdooX/Stock_Punto_Pedido)

Brach: dev_001

Comment: Now you try it work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The error was in "boolean" being the correct way "Boolean". You have an excellent view and a good knowledge. I'll add you in the thank-you code on github.

Regards,